# weighing percentage changes by number of samples

Tags: percentage, structural-change

Applying one simple formula for percentage change. This:

```
100 * (8 - 2) / 2 = 300%
```

gives the same results as this:

```
100 * (80 - 20) / 20 = 300%
```

However, one can argue that the second percentage change is more 'significant' in comparison to the first one, as it is based on larger number of samples.

Is there a way to weight the second percentage change higher? Thanks!

Comment: Where do 8, 2, 80, 20 come from?

Comment: Sorry. These are year on year changes 2-> 8, 20 -> 80. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: From your description, I cannot find the sample size, so "as it is based on larger number of samples" has no base.

Comment: In year X there were 8/80 samples and in year Y there were 2 /20 samples. That's what I mean.

Comment: Try to add the confidence interval if you really want to ESTIMATE something.